# ValueError in Titanic pipeline

Tags: python, pipeline, valueerror

I'm working on my first pipeline but I can't get it to work on the Titanic dataset. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

I dropped some features from the dataframe and used get dummies to transform categorical features.

```
titanic_dummies = titanic.copy()
titanic_dummies = titanic_dummies.drop([ 'Name', 'Ticket','Cabin', "Fare"], axis=1)
titanic_dummies = pd.get_dummies(titanic_dummies, drop_first=True)
```

Then I tried to run this pipeline

```
X=titanic_dummies.drop(['Survived'], axis=1)
y=titanic_dummies['Survived']


 ****#setup the pipeline steps****
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
         ('imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='most_frequent')),
         ('logreg', LogisticRegression())]
          
*# Create the pipeline: pipeline*
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

#Define hyperparameters and range of Grid Search
parameters = {"logreg__C": np.logspace(-5, 8, 15),
              "logreg__penalty": ['l1', 'l2']}

*# Create train and test sets*
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

*# run cross validation*
cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid = parameters, cv=3)

*# Fit the pipeline to the training set:* 
cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

*# Predict the labels of the test set*
y_pred = cv.predict(X_test)

*# Compute and print metrics*
print("Accuracy: {}".format(cv.score(X_test, y_test)))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
print("Tuned Model Parameters: {}".format(cv.best_params_))
```

**This is the error that I get**

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

From the attached picture you can probably tell that the size of my values are not the issue. Perhaps something goes wrong with my imputation?

[image: Titanic Data]

I really love to hear your thoughts on how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You may change

missing_values = "NaN"

to

missing_values = np.nan

this might work.

Answer (score 1):

The NaN's in the numpy arrray are represented as `np.NaN` not as string type `"NaN"`

Fix

```
('imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.NaN, strategy='most_frequent'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have any unwanted records. What I mean by this is that even though the dtypes say float, the Nans are a problem for your program. You have a couple of options here:

1. Delete such records
2. Fill them with the mean/median value (I wouldn't recommend it for titanic)
3. Replace them with a default value

Comment: I would recommend taking a look [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11928/valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for-dtypefloat32) for a resolution code-wise.